# Hive "argmin" failing without output

Tags: hive, verbose

I am currently trying to run a request on a table that looks like

```
Key Desc1 Desc2 Val
1   Hello World 37
2   Alpha Beta  27
2   Gamma Kappa 28
1   Bjr   Mde   42
```

My goal is to group by "Key" and ask for the line where Val=min(Vals) (in the group). For the dummy table above, I expect something like

```
Key Desc1 Desc2 Val
1   Hello World 37
2   Alpha Beta  27
```

To do so, I am using the following request:

```
select Key
       min(struct(Val,Desc1)).col2 as Desc1,
       min(struct(Val,Desc2)).col2 as Desc2,
       min(Val) as Val
from mytable;
```

When I try to execute the query, I do not have any error during the syntax checking but hive just hangs without creating any jobs. Then it fails with the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I do not have any idea of the exact reason of the fail. Do you see an obvious mistake in my query ?
*(if so, it should fail during the syntax check ; note that it fails "normally" if I introduce a mistake in the query like "col2" -> "col3")*

Do you know if we can force hive to display more information about the error ? I do not have seen a "verbose" mode but I may have missed it....

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straightforward using [Hive windowing functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).  Just take the `min()` over the window and then select the rows where `arg_min` and `Val` equal each other.

**Query**:

```
select Key, Desc1, Desc2, arg_min
from (
  select *
    , min(Val) over (partition by key) as arg_min
  from db.tbl ) x
where Val = arg_min
```

**Output**:

```
1    Hello    World    37
2    Alpha    Beta     27
```

Comment: +1 for this useful solution using windowing windows. Note however that this is only available in hive >0.11.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the query proposed in my question is correct and working (in hive 0.10 at least).

The problem was a pure "timeout" problem that can be solved by setting the configuration as follows:

```
set hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout=300;
```